# How do I subscribe to and raise an event within the same post method of my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, event-handling, signalr, webhooks

When an instance of my model `MyPost` is posted and it has a property with a certain value, e.g. `Type = "Question"`, I want to save the `Question`, subscribe to an event `NoMoreAnswers` and wait for a `NoMoreAnswers` event before returning the HTTP Response which will be a collection of `0` or more `MyPost` of `Type = "Answer"`. Each `MyPost` will have a unique Id.

When additional instance of `MyPost` come in with a Type of `Answer` they also need to be saved. Each `Answer` will also have its own unique id and a `RefId` pointing back to one of the Questions.

Finally when an instance of `MyPost` of `Type = "NoMoreAnswers"` is posted, also with its own unique id and with a `RefId` pointing back to one of the Questions, I want to raise the event `NoMoreAnswers`. Optionally, the `MyPost` instance with `Type = "NoMoreAnswers"` should also be saved. This raised event should cause the waiting `Question` to collect all the related `Answers` and return them as a collection of `MyPosts`. This will obviously mean that the `eventargs` will need to contain the `RefId` of the `NoMoreAnswers` post, and every waiting `Question` will have to examine the `eventargs` to see if the event is relevant to it, and if not go back to a waiting state.

Can someone help me get started? How does one define, subscribe to and raise events that are relevant in this situation? Is there a pattern that applies to this kind of problem that I should read up on?

Comment: Hi @DFlat. Welcome to SO. The web is a disconnected environment. There are no events. Only requests and responses. Also, please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Is something like WebHooks or SignalR worth considering in this situation? Or is there something more lightweight available that may help here? I have used neither, so I only know that they exist. Will WebHooks allow me to use the same class (my Controller) as both a Sender and a Receiver?

Comment: @JuanR - Thank you for pointing me to the how-to-ask document. I did read it - but would like your perspective on what specifically you would have wanted me to change/re-phrase to conform to the document.

Comment: For that, you should read this document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If I right  understand you, you need to use Session as a context for keeping and operating intermediate data between requests. See HttpContext Session.